# Filling nan with increasing sequence in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I try to translate this R code to pandas:

`data1 = data1 %>% mutate(id = ifelse(is.na(id), cumsum(is.na(id)), id))`

What it does - it looks for missing ID's and it gives them a unique number that is increasing (from 1 to ...).

I tried doing:

`df.assign(id = lambda x: x.isnull().cumsum() if x.isnull() else x)` but I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with specified columns name:

```
df.assign(id = lambda x: x['id'].mask(x['id'].isnull(), x['id'].isnull().cumsum()))
```

Comment: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat - missing last `)`

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast response! I have to wait 6 minutes until I can accept your answer. Maybe you can elaborate what mask does?